# cabal install llvm-general fails because of hardcoded directory

Tags: haskell, llvm, cabal

So i'm trying to install the llvm-3.4.2.2 haskell bindings through cabal. But it fails with the following output

```
Curtiss-MacBook-Air:TestImages Curtis$ sudo cabal install llvm-general
Password:
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/llvm-general-3.4.2.2-7647/llvm-general-3.4.2.2/Setup.hs, /tmp/llvm-general-3.4.2.2-7647/llvm-general-3.4.2.2/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /tmp/llvm-general-3.4.2.2-7647/llvm-general-3.4.2.2/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring llvm-general-3.4.2.2...
Building llvm-general-3.4.2.2...
Preprocessing library llvm-general-3.4.2.2...
dyld: Library not loaded: /Users/ian/zz64/ghc-7.6.3/libffi/build/inst/lib/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/tmp/llvm-general-3.4.2.2-7647/llvm-general-3.4.2.2/dist/build/LLVM/General/Internal/LibraryFunction_hsc_make
  Reason: image not found
running dist/build/LLVM/General/Internal/LibraryFunction_hsc_make failed (exit code 5)
command was: dist/build/LLVM/General/Internal/LibraryFunction_hsc_make  >dist/build/LLVM/General/Internal/LibraryFunction.hs
Failed to install llvm-general-3.4.2.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
llvm-general-3.4.2.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

It appears to fail because someone hardcoded the path `/Users/ian/zz64/ghc-7.6.3/libffi/build/inst/lib/libffi.6.dylib` in `LibraryFunction_hsc_make`. I've found people who have run into similar problems with this path but no viable solutions to my problem

Comment: This is a bug with libHSrts, not with llvm-general specially. Have you tried the workaround on the tracker?  https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5982

Comment: Still fails, also I'm using ghc-7.6.3 which this problem should be fixed for

Comment: Solved, the work around actually does solve the problem but I had to change libHSrts_thr-ghc7.6.3.dylib as well as libHSrts-ghc7.6.3.dylib, Thanks Stephen

Comment: @cpunerd I still got this error on my side. How can I fix it?